# QGIS python module is interfering with another python module installed at the system level

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, pip, qgis

I am working with QGIS Pisa in Windows environment.I wanted to upgrade the scipy module of Python present inside OSGeo4W. For that I installed pip from the OSGeo4W windows command shell. I closed the command shell after installation and reopened it.
When I give the pip command inside OSFGeo4W windows command shell, it is referring to pip module installed at the system level and hence I am getting an error. I don't know how to correct this thing. Here is my error stack trace:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Pisa\apps\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Pisa\apps\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals
    File "C:\Python27_32Bit\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Pisa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Pisa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Pisa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
    __import__('pip._vendor.packaging.specifiers')
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Pisa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\specifiers.py", line 275, in <module>
    class Specifier(_IndividualSpecifier):
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Pisa\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\specifiers.py", line 374, in Specifier
    re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE,
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Pisa\apps\Python27\lib\re.py", line 190, in compile return _compile(pattern, flags)
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Pisa\apps\Python27\lib\re.py", line 242, in _compile raise error, v # invalid expression
    sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

As you can see on the stacktrace, 3rd line from top, the code refers to pip module of python installed at the system level instead of pip module installed inside the QGIS Pisa. How can I correctly run this ?